# Mongodb count sum of fields in a collection with conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have collections in mongoDb like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(""),
  fieldA: "123",
  fieldB: {
      subFieldB:[
           {
             fieldC: ""
           },
           {
             fieldC: ""
           },
           {
             fieldC: ""
           }
      ]
  }    
},
{
  _id: ObjectId(""),
  fieldA: "123",
  fieldB: {
      subFieldB:[
           {
             fieldC: ""
           },
           {
             fieldC: ""
           },
           {
             fieldC: ""
           }
      ]
  }    
},
{
  _id: ObjectId(""),
  fieldA: "456",
  fieldB: {
      subFieldB:[
           {
             fieldC: ""
           },
           {
             fieldC: ""
           },
           {
             fieldC: ""
           }
      ]
  }    
}
```

I want to get sum of number of subFieldB where fieldA is "123"
So the goal is getting something like *{sumOfSubFieldB: 6}*

I tried aggregate like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match : { "fieldA" : "123" }
    },
   {
      $project: {
         numberOfFieldB: { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$fieldB.subFieldB" }, then: { $size: "$fieldB.subFieldB" }, else: "NA"} },
      }
   }
] )
```

So far I get sum of fieldB per doc like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(""),
    "numberOfFieldB" : 3
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId(""),
    "numberOfFieldB" : 3
}
```

How should I do the query to get total number of fieldB?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, or something similar with $group:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [{
        $match: {
            "fieldA": "123"
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: "$fieldA",
            count: { 
                $sum: { $size: "$fieldB.subFieldB" } }
        }
    }]
);
```

Comment: Change _id of $group, you need to group by right _id, try with $fieldB

Comment: My apologise I tried it again with fieldA as _id and get:
{
    "_id" : <fieldA>,
    "total" : 0
}

Comment: So try with `_id: "$fieldB"`

Comment: See now, my first approach was right, but I've tried to get sum instead of count. So now would be fine.